# button that is linked to switch method

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, switch-statement

I try to switch the date for 2 buttons and one displaying date.
this is the button code:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 150px">Startdate</td>
    <td style="width: 16px">
        <a id="previousButton" href="@Url.Action(MVC.ImportUbs.Default.Index())" class='@(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ReportSettingsViewModel.PreviousBusinessDateText) ? "left-icon" : "left-icon-disabled")' title="@Model.ReportSettingsViewModel.PreviousBusinessDateText" data-form-method="get" onclick=' $("#action").val("previous"); '></a>
    </td>

    <td style="width: 200px">@Html.TextBoxForDate(m => m.ReportSettingsViewModel.BusinessDate, new { @class = "date" })</td>
    <td style="width: 16px">
        <a id="nextButton" href="@Url.Action(MVC.ImportUbs.Default.Index())" class='@(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ReportSettingsViewModel.NextBusinessDateText) ? "right-icon" : "right-icon-disabled")' title="@Model.ReportSettingsViewModel.NextBusinessDateText" data-form-method="get" onclick=' $("#action").val("next"); '></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the method i would like to send it to. where it can change the dates:

```
public void Search(IDataModule dm, string action = "")
{
    switch (action)
    {
        case "next":
            BusinessDate = NextBusinessDate;
            NextBusinessDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            break;
        case "previous":
            BusinessDate = PreviousBusinessDate;
            PreviousBusinessDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            break;
    }

    PreviousBusinessDate = dm.GetPreviousStatusDate(BusinessDate);
    NextBusinessDate = dm.GetNextStatusDate(BusinessDate);
}
```

I have a list with dates. It selects the latest date possible and then looks if there is a date before it that is available and a date after it. When i press the button it should replace the current date with the previous or next date and it should replace the next or previous with the first date coming after or before the current date.
Can somebody help me with this?
Only thing i need to know is how to get information to the switch that is in another model while the buttons are in a partial view.

Comment: help with what exactly?

Comment: You have 2 links with identical href attributes that do not pass any parameters to your method. What are you expecting to do?

Comment: I have a box with dates. the date that is selected is the date that must be the same with the information from the database. the date has to change when i hit the button. that is the only thing left.

Comment: None of this makes any sense. Do you want to pass the value `"next"` to the method when you click one button and `"previous"` when you click the other? Your method is not doing anything except setting some variables which are lost the moment it exits the method. And you cant have an interface as a parameter of your method. You need to explain what your trying to so.

Comment: watch the new explanation please. i hope i made it all clear

Comment: stephen can you please look into it again?

Comment: @astijn3457 (if you want to notify someone, see how this comment starts). Nothing in your question or code makes any sense at all. What on earth do you think `onclick=' $("#action").val("previous");` would do? What is the point of your `Search()` method (refer my previous comment)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I wanted to use the onlick to go to the search method.
didn't know how to do it but I fixed it in a totally different way.